# Stackapply error in a mean function with several rasters

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I can't use stackApply function because resultings layers has NA values. Always I use calc because its works but I can't understand the stackApply error. I think the error can be a memory error in the allocation of the file.

```
r_name<-str_sub(r_files,-12,-5);r_name

idx<-as.Date(r_name, format = "%Y%m%d")

NDVI<-stack(r_files)

rstack <- setZ(NDVI,idx)

NDVI_monthly <- stackApply(rstack,indices=format(idx,"%Y%m"), mean, na.rm = T)

NDVI_monthly
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 257, 408, 104856, 240  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.002245788, 0.002245788  (x, y)
extent     : -72.60858, -71.6923, -46.30366, -45.72649  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
source     : C:/Users/TPPC/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp4WFTTP/raster/r_tmp_2020-02-02_105108_2972_39673.grd 
names      : index_200002, index_200003, index_200004, index_200005, index_200006, index_200007, index_200008, index_200009, index_200010, index_200011, index_200012, index_200101, index_200102, index_200103, index_200104, ... 
min values :           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA, ... 
max values :           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA,           NA, ...
```

Comment: I would think if it's a memory error, you would get a corresponding error message. But it's hard to help you without a reproducible example. So, if you can please provide one

Comment: It only occurs when you use `stackapply`, I had this issue as well.